# bootstrap4 nav bar item extending past

Tags: html, django-bootstrap4

With bootstrap4 the top navbar displays properly, but when i reduce the size of the screen the search bar extends past.

Navigation.html

```
{% load static %}
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="{% static "polls/images/background.gif" %}"> Lorem Ipsum</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarMenu">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">User</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Products</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>        
    </nav>
```

[image]

Blog.html

```
        <div class="row content">
          <div class="col-sm-3 sidenav">

            <ul class="nav flex-column nav nav-pills">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                </li>
            </ul>           

            <form class="form-inline md-form mr-auto mb-4">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <span class="fas">&#xf002;</span>

            </form>

          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-9">
                <h4><small>RECENT POSTS</small></h4>
                <hr>
                <h2>I Love Food</h2>
                <h5><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> Post by Jane Dane, Sep 27, 2015.</h5>
                <h5><span class="badge badge-danger">Food</span> <span class="badge badge-primary">Ipsum</span></h5><br>
                <p>Food is my passion. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                <br><br>

                <h4><small>RECENT POSTS</small></h4>
                <hr>
                <h2>Officially Blogging</h2>
                <h5><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> Post by John Doe, Sep 24, 2015.</h5>
                <h5><span class="badge badge-success">Lorem</span></h5><br>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                <hr>

                <h4>Leave a Comment:</h4>
                <form role="form">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" required></textarea>
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                </form>
                <br><br>

                <p><span class="badge">2</span> Comments:</p><br>

                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-2 text-center">
                    <img src="bandmember.jpg" class="img-circle" height="65" width="65" alt="Avatar">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <h4>Anja <small>Sep 29, 2015, 9:12 PM</small></h4>
                    <p>Keep up the GREAT work! I am cheering for you!! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                    <br>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-2 text-center">
                    <img src="bird.jpg" class="img-circle" height="65" width="65" alt="Avatar">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <h4>John Row <small>Sep 25, 2015, 8:25 PM</small></h4>
                    <p>I am so happy for you man! Finally. I am looking forward to read about your trendy life. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                    <br>
                    <p><span class="badge">1</span> Comment:</p><br>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center">
                        <img src="bird.jpg" class="img-circle" height="65" width="65" alt="Avatar">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-10">
                        <h4>Nested Bro <small>Sep 25, 2015, 8:28 PM</small></h4>
                        <p>Me too! WOW!</p>
                        <br>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>



</div>
```

if i use bootstrap3 the example works, but the top nav bar does not display properly at top of the page.
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_temp_blog&stacked=h

Index.html

```
{% extends 'polls/base.html'%}
{% load static %}

{%block content%}
{% include "polls/blog.html" %}
{%endblock%}

{% block footer %}
{% include "polls/footer.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

Base.html

```
    {% load static %}

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

      <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
      <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
      <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'polls/style.css' %}">

      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'polls/style.css' %}">
    </head>

    <body>

        {% block navblock %}
        {% include "polls\navigation.html" %}
        {% endblock %}

        {% block content %}
        <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
            <div class="container">
                <h1 class="display-4">Fluid jumbotron</h1>
            <p class="lead">This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its parent.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endblock %}

        {% block footer %}
        {% include "polls\footer.html" %}
        {% endblock %}

        <div class="container my-4">

                <p class="font-weight-bold">Bootstrap cookie consent is a simple, not-invasive popup which displays information about cookies and privacy policy.</p>

                <p><strong>Detailed documentation and more examples you can find in our <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/modals/basic/"
                                                                                           target="_blank">Bootstrap Modals Docs</a> </p>

                <hr>

                <p class="font-weight-bold">Basic example</p>

              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalCookie1">Launch modal</button>

                  <!--Modal: modalCookie-->
                  <div class="modal fade top" id="modalCookie1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
                    aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-frame modal-top modal-notify modal-info" role="document">
                      <!--Content-->
                      <div class="modal-content">
                        <!--Body-->
                        <div class="modal-body">
                          <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">

                            <p class="pt-3 pr-2">We use cookies to improve your website experience</p>

                            <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Learn more
                              <i class="fas fa-book ml-1"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Ok, thanks</a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <!--/.Content-->
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!--Modal: modalCookie-->
              </div>

              <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
              <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
              <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </body>


    </html>
```

What do i need to do to fix the side nav using bootstrap4?

[image]

Comment: Most likely some css property affects the input min-width, try inspecting the element.

Comment: Have you tried using `form-control-sm` class on the search control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using `div.imput-group` which may enchance the styling. Check the Bootstrap input group [component reference](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/) with more details on the class.

```
 <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search this blog">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can always work around bootstrap by giving it a custom (non-bootstrap class) and using a media query in css when it hits the size that's causing issues.